# Does making an apk take two hours?

Tags: android

I have asked someone to make me an app. I want to test it and asked him if he can email me the apk twice every day with the changes he made that day.

He told me it takes too long to set up that apk twice every day, that it takes a couple of hours. Is that true?

Comment: Compiling the apk takes seconds, when done manually. If you are talking about setting up an automated build system, then that's another story.

Comment: merely building an apk out of what you have done is a matter of minutes (sarcastically, if not seconds). But the effort that you put to really take the development forward so that you get a new feature that goes into the APK can take several hours.

Comment: Perhaps making a commit into version control two times a day would be an alternative.

Comment: If the application is in the final stages, and it's just bugfinding and general testing left, I don't see a problem with sending an .apk twice a day, especially if you get a good and constructive response from the client (which doesn't happen too often...). But if the development just started I can see the problem. Usually you have code that won't even run, because you're working on the layout or something like that, and it is likely that the client will complain that this and that won't work, which is just annoying and distracting for the developer.

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't take hours, but 2 time every day ????

It's crazy! How can he work if has to make a delivery 2 time a day? Even the most paranoid of my managers will ask a maximum of 2 delivery a week.

Comment: i know. I needed to test him. He kleeps postponing and now he sent me an apk that is not very good. So i asked him to fix bugs and he doesnt seem to be able to do it

Answer (score 3):

Well, no, it takes less than 5 minutes (for me at least, including writing an email, finding his mail adress buried under ten tons of paper, and getting a cup of coffee).

What I cannot understand is why you would like a build two times a day.

Comment: he keeps telling me that it takes this long while the client wants results.

Answer (score 2):

If the App is ridiculously large - it might take a few minutes. Otherwise it takes less than a minute once you have your key generated. It does for me atleast (my App has some 50+ classes).

A build two times a day seems a bit overkill - unless your at a point where you're doing minor bug fixes.

Answer (score 0):

That's not true as far as I've noticed. Exporting an Android project with Eclipse into an .apk file takes literally 10 seconds or less on my machine. I can imagine with large projects it will take longer but if it takes several hours, well, you're doing it wrong.

To me, it just sounds like he is trying to find creative ways to spend more time making the app, without having to show you the progress. As in "I'm sorry I didn't get more done today but since it takes several hours to build this .apk twice a day you're taking a whole lot of time of my hands."